# How to bind mat-chip to ngmodel in Angular 6 with Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ngmodel, md-chip

I have a form in a mat-dialog who displays multiple fields. Most of them are input and work perfectly, they are binded with [(ngModel)] as shown below, but I would like a field with mat-chips and autocomplete (like [here](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview)). My problem is that I don't know how to bind the selected chips with [(ngModel)] get the data.

**My *HTML* :**

```
<form class="mat-dialog-content" (ngSubmit)="submit" #formControl="ngForm">
<div class="form">
  <mat-form-field color="accent">
    <input matInput #inputname class="form-control" placeholder="Nom du WOD" [(ngModel)]="data.name" name="name" maxlength="50" required >
    <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
    <mat-hint align="end">{{inputname.value?.length || 0}}/50</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="form">
  <mat-form-field color="accent">
    <input matInput placeholder="Notes du coach" [(ngModel)]="data.coachesNotes" name="coachesNotes">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="form">
  <mat-form-field class="chip-list" aria-orientation="horizontal">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList [(ngModel)]="data.movementsIds" name="movementsIds">
      <mat-chip
        *ngFor="let mouv of mouvs"
        [selectable]="selectable"
        [removable]="removable"
        (removed)="remove(mouv)">
        {{mouv}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
      <input
        placeholder="Ajouter un mouvement..."
        #mouvInput
        [formControl]="mouvCtrl"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
        [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
      />
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selectedChip($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let mouv of filteredMouvs | async" [value]="mouv">
        {{ mouv }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button [type]="submit" [disabled]="!formControl.valid" [mat-dialog-close]="1" (click)="confirmAdd()">Ajouter</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">Annuler</button>
</div></form>
```

**My *component* :**

```
public confirmAdd(): void {
  this.dataService.addWod(this.data);
}
```

[View of my filled form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdGoI.png)

When I click on the "add" button my item is added with all of the others fields but the "movementsIds" field is null as we can see [in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HOoC.png).

Thanks you in advance for any help you can bring me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who could have the same problem, I've found a solution.

Instead of bind the chip list to my "data.movementsIds" with [(ngModel)] I just pass the "mouvs" array to my "confirmAdd" function and then set the data.movementsIds with this array like that :

**HTML :**

```
  <mat-form-field class="chip-list" aria-orientation="horizontal">
    <mat-chip-list #chipList>
      <mat-chip
        *ngFor="let mouv of mouvs"
        [removable]="removable"
        (removed)="remove(mouv)">
        {{mouv}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
      <input
        placeholder="Ajouter un mouvement..."
        #mouvInput
        [formControl]="movementsIds"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
        [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"/>
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selectedChip($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let mouv of filteredMouvs | async" [value]="mouv">
        {{ mouv }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**Component :**

```
public confirmAdd(mouvs: Array<any>): void {
   this.data.movementsIds = JSON.stringify(mouvs);
   this.dataService.addWod(this.data);
}
```

Comment: can you provide your demo project link in online editor. thanks

Comment: @samhot Without ngModel, template-driven form validation will not work